# Android client connecting to Python server side code on Apache

Tags: android, python, client-server, server-side

I am finished with an Android client code, its working; and for the time being the data that was supposed to be received from apache http server was emulated to get data from sd card.

Now, I am working on the server side code in Python, using the socket library; and testing the default socket example from python socket documentation.

The problem I am facing is that the Android client can't connect to this server side code.

Android side code trying to connect:

```
urlString = "http://10.0.2.2/cgi-bin/serverconnect.py";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
try{
httpConn.connect();
......
}
```

Where serverconnect.py is:

```
# Echo server program
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'     # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 80              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

Clues, and hints are required from experts...
Thanks

Comment: Can you connect to your server from something other than your android device, e.g. your web browser? What if you change the server host to `10.0.2.2`? Also, your server process probably requires high privileges to be able to bind to port 80 (are you seeing `socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied`).

Comment: What error are you seeing on the client and/or server?  You may just need to call httpConn.getInputStream() for the response to be returned.

Comment: yes, the web browser is working, have tried both the 10.0.2.2 and the ip address of the server. Also the code in python can't have 10.0.2.2 as this is server code running on pc on apache httpd.

Comment: @mhawke: no error, could be seen. The code just throws IO exception on httpcon.connect()

Comment: Could not access the server from browser outside android. Any hints how to make this run...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem with this code is solved, which was the target Android version was 3.x +
So I needed to use a different thread for the network access. Have started a new thread with a different problem so thanks everyone for responding.